# C# read a file and search for changes

Tags: c#

I'm a C# beginner and I want to make a program that reads a config file every 30 seconds and checks for some changes in specific values.

The values I am searching for are not always at the same line number and so I am searching for the values by their key names.  I want to find the key and then check if the value has changed.

To begin with I am testing to see if I can find the correct key in the config file.

Here is what I have tried. My problem is that I have called this function with the following input:

```
check_for_changes("TEXTURE_MAX_LOAD =");
```

and I am expecting my TextBox `testtb` to contain the word `changes` after calling the method, but the TextBox is remaining blank.

```
public string check_for_changes(string value)
{
    int counter = 0;
    string line;


    System.IO.StreamReader file =
        new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\EFB\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\FSXDemo\fsx.CFG");

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(value))
        {
            testtb.Text = "changes";
            break;
        }

        counter++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Line number: {0}", counter);

    file.Close();
    return value;
}
```

Comment: To be of much help, we'd probably need to know what the layout of the file is.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Along with knowing the layout of the file, can you tell us what is going wrong or why the code you have posted is not working? What is the problem with it? Are you getting exceptions? Is there an error trying to read the file? What is the problem you are stuck on? From your question it is unclear. You have stated what your goal is and shown us your current code, but have not explained what is going wrong or why this code is not working.

Comment: you may consider also [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: thnx for reply 
so, you can see i wrote             testtb.Text = "changes"; but i don't have any text in the text box after i made a change in the file and i use             check_for_changes("TEXTURE_MAX_LOAD =");
i want to do a test for trying to find then i'll see about cheking the changes

Comment: This is information that should be added to your question. Are you sure that there is a space in property value in that config file? You wrote `"TEXTURE_MAX_LOAD ="`, but could it be `"TEXTURE_MAX_LOAD="` You are using string matching so it has to be exact. I would consider maybe even just searching for `"TEXTURE_MAX_LOAD"` and see if you get a result.

Comment: ok i'll se in 2 min

Comment: yeah that was the problem in finding the line thank you 
now if i want to see if this line TEXTURE_MAX_LOAD=4096 has changes in 30 sec i mean i want to stay cheking every 30 sec because maybe it changes to TEXTURE_MAX_LOAD=1024

Comment: You should give it a go yourself first and if you get stuck, ask another question. To help point you in the right direction, you might want to take a look at [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this code where you want to start checking:

```
 System.Windows.Forms.Timer Timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 30000 };
 Timer.Tick += (obj, arg) =>
 {
     check_for_changes("TEXTURE_MAX_LOAD =");
 };
 Timer.Start();
```

Be careful !!! if you want to end this Timer or you want to stop/start it again, you must declare it globally.

and the function should be like:

```
 private string LastValue = "";
 public string check_for_changes(string value)
 {
     int counter = 0;
     string line;


     System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\EFB\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\FSXDemo\fsx.CFG");

     while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         if (line.Contains(value))
         {
             string NewValue = line.Substring(value.Length);
             if (NewValue != LastValue)
                  testtb.Text = "new Value is : " + NewValue;
             LastValue = NewValue;
             break;
         }

         counter++;
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Line number: {0}", counter);

     file.Close();
     return value;
 }
```

this function will works.

Comment: Yes, but you must take care of exceptions. if your program (and specially file operation) doesn't throw the exceptions it works; please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ioexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: how will i make an exception when the programme doesn't find the file ?

Comment: you can use Try/Catch block. there are several exception in IO operation that are listed in above link (in previous comment). for example: try { // put all codes here ..... } catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex) { MessageBox.Show("File not found"); }